# Convert table into row-column matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a table which I would like to convert into matrix of rows and columns:

```
x=read.table("file")
10716052        AF004884    2       AutonomicNervousDisorders
10716052        AF004884    11      CardiovascularDisorders
10716052        AF004884    9       GastrointestinalDisorders
10716052        AF004884    2       Hemorrhage
10716052        AF004884    1       MetabolicandNutritionalDisorders
10716052        AF004884    2       Musculo-skeletalSystem
10716052        AF004884    5       NervousSystem
10716052        AF004884    4       OphthalmicDisorders
10716052        AF004884    7       PathologicalDisorders
10716052        AF004884    5       PulmonaryDisorders
10716052        AF004884    2       RespiratorySystem
10716052        AF004884    3       SkinandAppendages
10716052        AJ251368    2       AutonomicNervousDisorders
10716052        AJ251368    11      CardiovascularDisorders
10716052        AJ251368    9       GastrointestinalDisorders
10716052        AJ251368    2       Hemorrhage
10716052        AJ251368    1       MetabolicandNutritionalDisorders
```

I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126108/convert-table-into-matrix-by-column-names) which says to use "library reshape" in R.

```
library(reshape)
cast(x, V1 ~ V2)
```

But I am getting the additive results:

```
        V1 AF004884 AJ251368 AJ272268 L35901 M65212
1 10716052       12       12       12     12      1
```

I would like to have each instance of the column names with their respective counts as they belong to different categories.

Comment: which column denotes category information? The last one?

Comment: Yes,The last column is category information.

Comment: I have tried this from ecodist package:                                                     >  crosstab(a$V2,a$V3,a$V4):                                                                                         
         AF004884 AJ251368 AJ272268 L35901 M65212
10716052       53       53       53     42      2
But Its giving me additive results from column V4,I want them to be as it is as per the categories.

Comment: Can you try `cast(x, V3 ~ V1, value="V2")` Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Actually I need V3 ~ V2, value="V4") but it still gives me additive results.

Comment: This?: `cast(x, V4 ~ V1 + V2, value="V3")` The leftmost column is gonna be the categories. The column name will V1*V2. It's gonna look like this: http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/9674/t740.png